# 240v 3kw sauna heater connections

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

Im trying to wire a sauna heater. Im using #12 wire as directed in the instruction manual (directions say 3x12awg 12.5 amp). The wire I purchased has 4 wires in it, two hots, a neutral, and a ground.

Here's the diagram, which confuses me:

[image: Sauna circuit diagram]

Is the neutral not required for this application? One hot in L1, one hot in L2, and the bare ground into slot 1 with the ground symbol? If this is the case, do i just leave the neutral wire not connected to anything?

Comment: Yeah, lots of heater loads don't need neutral.  Water heater etc.

Answer (score 4):

### You indeed don't need the neutral wire, just cap it off with a wirenut

Your sauna heater requires 240V only, not both 120 and 240V, so it has no use for the neutral wire.  You are correct that one hot goes into L1, the other hot goes into L2, and the bare ground goes to the ground symbol.  As to the neutral wire? Just cap it off with a wirenut.  (It's cheap insurance in case the next sauna heater that goes there *does* need a neutral, say to run its timer.  Yours doesn't since yours has a timer that runs off 240V.)